# Script that starts with boot and auto-restart on failure

Tags: boot, bash, scripts, startup

I'm trying to write an auto start script that starts on boot and restarts if it crashes. The start on boot is doable by simply adding the script to the

```
/etc/rc.local
```

File, however my problem is the auto restart. I thought about exporting the $$ Variable into an external text file before starting the actual script, and using this with another script to check whether that pid still is running or not. My question is now how to check if a specific PID is still running and also if there is a more reliable way to do this.

Comment: But what if, say, the script hangs but doesn't crash?

Comment: That's why I'm searching for a more reliable way. Also this script consists of letting several programs running. I've seen it crashing for dozens of times but not freezing once. But as you said, that'd be a problem

Comment: Can't systemd do that with the restart option in the `.service` file?

Comment: Could you explain that a bit @George ?

Comment: I know that `systemd` files have a command that's included in the `[Service]` section to restart a service it stops or fails to start, I have to look it up

Comment: This is it `Restart With this option enabled, the service is restarted after its process exits, with the exception of a clean stop by the systemctl command.`

Comment: The options for it could be: `on-success", "on-failure", "on-abnormal", "on-abort", or "on-watchdog"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your script needs to perform in such a manner is `systemd` sevice.

An example would be the one below:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Script


[Service]
Type=forking    
ExecStart=/path/to/script
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This can be done in several ways:

1. Place your script in another location and access it from your `systemd` service files.
2. Place the code directly in the `systemd` service file.

I believe the first option is ideal in your situation. Now once done enable at boot with the normal `systemctl` commands, such as:

```
sudo systemctl enable myscript.service
sudo systemctl status myscript.service
sudo systemctl stop myscript.service
sudo systemctl start myscript.service
```

Sources:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-systemd-units-and-unit-files

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html